# how to update a column with multiple row separated by comma in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

The are Two table

```
table stud
id   name  marks1 marks 2
1     X     3      2
2     y     4      2
3     z     5      2
```

2nd Table Comment

```
comment
```

update the comment column with rows of stud in the given format
Expected Result

Table Comment

```
 comment
 1,X,3,2#2,y,4,2#3,z,5,2
```

Comment: Have you made *any* effort to do this yourself? If so, please post what you have, and why/how it's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc10f/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table stud
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10),
  marks1 int,
  marks2 int
)

create table comment
(
  comment varchar(max)
)

insert into stud values
(1,     'X',     3,      2),
(2,     'y',     4,      2),
(3,     'z',     5,      2)
```

**Query 1**:

```
insert into comment(comment)
select
  (
  select '#'+cast(id as varchar(10))+','+
             name+','+
             cast(marks1 as varchar(10))+','+
             cast(marks2 as varchar(10))
  from stud
  for xml path(''), type
  ).value('substring((./text())[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc10f/2/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from comment
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc10f/2/1)**:

```
|                 COMMENT |
---------------------------
| 1,X,3,2#2,y,4,2#3,z,5,2 |
```